# Unable to spilit a String with '\' character using JAVA

Tags: java, split, substring, directory-structure

I am trying to recreate a folder structure in Windows system using JAVA program.I am getting the intended filepath from another system as String argument in my java program and am supposed to spilit the filepath String to identify folder names at each level.
The '\'(part of filepath string in windows systems) when used along with other legit characters in a string behaves differently. It is combining with the following characters in the string and produces different results(generates different characters because ascii value of \00 is different from that of \ separately and 0 separately).

```
String WindowsFilePath="drivename\folderName1\00000innerFolderName\03thefileName.fileExtension";
```

Is possible to spilit this String using JAVA code to

```
"drivename","folderName1","00000innerFolderName","03thefileName.fileExtension"
```

Additional Information on root cause of this issue:

I have a old directory structure where someone created folders with names like '001thImageFolder' 'firstImageFolder' etc in filesystem. Now if I get the filepath of a file that is inside a directory named in the above fashion the '\' that comes in filepath got appended with the first or first and second characters of the folder name and gets automatically converted to a escape sequence.  I want to eliminate this escape sequence conversion.

Comment: instead of writing \ you need to write \\

Comment: but you could just use `File.separator` and append that instead

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes agreed.I have escapesequences in my string. But introducing '\\' instead of '\' in that string is not in my hand. I am getting a feed to my javaprogram with a string like this. So is there a way to do this spilit using java?

Comment: what is the response that you receive from the feed?

Answer (score 5):

There are no backslashes in your string.

Only escape sequences:

- `\f` = form feed character
- `\0` = nul char (hex zero)

However, if you *did* have backslashes:

```
String parts = str.split("\\\\");
```

Note the double double backslash; doubled once to create a single backslash character in a string literal, and doubled *again* to create a literal backslash in the *regex*.

---

I think your intention is for the string literal to be:

```
String windowsFilePath ="drivename\\folderName1\\00000innerFolderName\\03thefileName.fileExtension";
```

Comment: @thomas actually it's more tragic than that - see edited answer

Comment: yes that is my intention. How to change 'String WindowsFilePath="drivename\folderName1\00000innerFolderName\03thefileName.fileExtension";'   to  'String windowsFilePath ="drivename\\folderName1\\00000innerFolderName\\03thefileName.fileExtension";'